# JDBC - No connection is available - SpringBoot/Hikari/JPA - spring.jpa.open-in-view

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, hikaricp

We are facing now JDBC connection issue while we run load test. it goes well for few hours but suddenly thread starts going into pending state.
I have checked code and i could not find we are leaking any connection by intention. Only smoke I can see in logs is related to JPA call we make.  but still it does not answer why we hitting no connection issue. any suggestion will be help ful.

Tech Stack -
We are using Spring Boot 2.4.7, Hibernate 5.4.25, Hikari CP 3.4.5, JPA 2.2

Logs -

1 [LogType:Usage] DEBUG [payment-service,,] [15] [HikariPool-1 connection adder] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@44a351b0

---

2. [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask] Connection leak detection triggered for org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@44a351b0 on thread http-nio-8080-exec-10, stack trace follows \u2028java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected\u2028    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)\u2028    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)\u2028   at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)\u2028   at

---

3. [LogType:Usage]  [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask] Previously reported leaked connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@44a351b0 on thread http-nio-8080-exec-10 was returned to the pool (unleaked)

---

4. [HikariPool-1 connection closer] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase] HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@44a351b0: (connection has passed maxLifetime)

But in between we see and it is where our load test start failing ->

[LogType:Usage] DEBUG [14] [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=15, active=15, idle=0, waiting=75)

---

Configuration -
connectionleakthreshold - 3000 ( we event tried with 30000 but found same behaviour)
connection-timeout - 30000

Answer (score 0):

Please read for property - spring.jpa.open-in-view

https://raul8804.wordpress.com/2019/03/31/spring-boot-project-db-connection-leak-investigation/

This is very much strange how Spring adds transaction for all controllers.